# Putting integers into a list from a text file

Tags: python, list, text-files

I have a text file and I need to put the numbers in this file into a list like this: `[[123,456],[234,567],[345,678]...]` but I don't know how to do this as I ran into some error messages shown below.

My text file looks something like this (the `-->` are arrows in the original text file, but I don't know what they look like if I read the file using `with open`:

```
# These are the ids for blablabla
# put the ids into a list like this [[123,456],[234,567],[345,678]...]
#id1 --> id2
#123 --> 456
#234 --> 567
#345 --> 678
#456 --> 789
```

What I tried to do initially was

```
with open('mytxt.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in range(3):
        next(f)
    for line in f:
        lst = list(map(int,line.split(',')))
        print(lst)[:10]
```

After running this, I got an error message `<!-- language: lang-js --> invalid literal for int() with base 10: '123\t456\n'` so I thought about stripping the `'\n'` and the `'t'` at the end of each line by running the following code:

```
with open('ca-GrQc.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in range(4):
        next(f)
    for line in f:
        lst = list(map(int,line.strip('\n').strip('t').split(',')))
        print(lst)[:10]
```

After running that I still got an error message `invalid literal for int() with base 10: '123\t456'` which I have no idea where the `'t'` comes from (and I am sure that `'t'` was not in the orginal file).

**Does anyone know why that happens and how to solve it, or is there a more efficient way of putting the numbers from the text file into a list?**

Comment: it looks like a tab character so you should split the line on that character

Comment: Should you be doing `split('\t')` as the `--->` might be your editor's way of displaying tabs?

Comment: Instead of `lst = list(map(int,line.strip('\n').strip('t').split(',')))`, try `lst = [int(number) for number in line.split("\t")]`. As others have mentioned `\t` is an escape sequence for the tab character. I've also replace you `map` with a list comprehension which is the ore standard way to do this in Python. You also need some outer list that you append to i.e. `outer_list.append(lst)` in your loop and be sure to initialise it as `outer_list = []` *before* your loop.

Comment: It works! Thank you all very much

Comment: @Dan: `map` is perfectly standard; as what is admittedly an opinion I’d even call it preferable to introducing a variable name that could be, but isn’t, used in a non-trivial way.  If you want a list comprehension, use it for the outer list and avoid the loop entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to achieve your expected output.

```
import re
file1 = open("names_file.txt", "r")
l = file1.readlines()
new_list = []
for i in l:
    m = re.findall(r'\d+', i)
    new_list.append(m)
print(new_list)
```

Above code will give a list containing strings, if you want to convert it into integer type then add this code. This will give your expected output.

```
for j in range(len(new_list)):
    for k in range(2):
        new_list[j][k] = int(new_list[j][k])
print(new_list)
```

There are two print statement in above code one will give list of list of string, and after conversion it will give list of list of integers.
[image: Output]